# Showing that $\int_{|z|=2} \frac{1}{z^2+z+1}\,dz = 0$ without partial fractions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = z^2 + z + 1 $ and let $\gamma$ be the circle $|z|=2 $. I want to find

$$ \int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{f(z)}\, dz $$

I know the roots of $f(z) $ are $z= \frac{ 3i - 1}{2}, \frac{ -3i -1 }{2} $. Hence, if we use the partial fractions decomposition we can use Cauchy's integral formula to obtain our result.

Is there a way to obtain this integral without using the partial fractions?

Comment: Polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$ are analytic. Your integral will always be zero. Perhaps you mean $\int_{\gamma}(1/f)\,dz$?

Comment: yes, sorry, I meant $1/f$

Comment: The roots of $f(z)$ should be $( -1 \pm i\sqrt{3})/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Both singularities $\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt3}{2}$ lie on the unit circle. By Cauchy's integral theorem, 
$$
\int_{|z| = R} \frac{1}{z^2+z+1}\,dz
$$
is independent of $R$ for $R > 1$. On the other hand, by the (reverse) triangle inequality and the standard estimation lemma ("the $ML$-lemma"):
$$
\left| \int_{|z| = R} \frac{1}{z^2+z+1}\,dz \right| \le \frac{2\pi R}{R^2-R-1}
$$
so
$$
\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{|z| = R} \frac{1}{z^2+z+1}\,dz = 0
$$
but since the integral is constant in $R$,
$$
\int_{|z| = R} \frac{1}{z^2+z+1}\,dz = 0
$$
for all $R > 1$.

Of course, it's also possible to directly compute the integral, for example using the residue theorem or partial fractions+Cauchy's integral formula.